# Visual studio code user snippets capitalize not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I wrote such code

```
"State": {
    "prefix": "state",
    "body": [
        "const [$1, set${1:/capitalize}] = useState($2);"
    ],
    "description": "Adds state"
},
```

I expect that the result will be (if I enter `test` in $1) like this:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState($2);
```

But I get such result:

```
const [/capitalize, set/capitalize] = useState();
```

In official docs I found such rule: `'${' int ':' '/upcase' | '/downcase' | '/capitalize' '}'`.

Could you please tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below snippet for the requested output:

```
const [$1, set${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}] = useState($2);
```

Output will be (in case I enter $1 as test):

```
const [test, setTest] = useState();
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at why your version `${1:/capitalize}` doesn't work:

Here is a portion of the snippet grammar you cited from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

```
tabstop     ::= '$' int
                | '${' int '}'
                | '${' int  transform '}'

 -snip-

transform   ::= '/' regex '/' (format | text)+ '/' options

format      ::= '$' int | '${' int '}'
                | '${' int ':' '/upcase' | '/downcase' | '/capitalize' '}'
```

So initially it looks like `${1:/capitalize}` is correct, just looking at the last line of the grammar above it seems

`${' int ':' '/capitalize'`

is a valid option.  But you have to track through the grammar to use it properly.  The `format` syntax can only be used in a `transform`. We see this in:

`transform   ::= '/' regex '/' (format | text)+ '/' options`

So right there your version does not include a transform.  You do not have the necessary `regex` preceder.  So those `'/upcase' | '/downcase' | '/capitalize'` options can only be used as part of a transform with a regex (although you can have an empty regex but that doesn't help you and you still need to have the regex entry point anyhow).

Here is the general form of a transform:

`${someInt/regex captures here/do something with the captures here, like ${1:/capitalize} /}`

Note that the first `$someInt` is a tabstop - it could be `$1` for example, but the second `$1` (with the capitalize) is **NOT a tabstop** but a reference to the **first capture group** from the preceding regex.  So a transform can only transform something that has been captured by a regex.

The grammar requires that the `format` option be part of a `transform`, and a transform requires a `regex` and `$n`'s in the `format` part refer to capture groups and not tabstop variables.

I hope this all makes sense.